# Messed up Windows 10 pro accounts

Tags: user-accounts

I am a prolific computer user and have 3 windows 10 desktops and also a MAC mini on the same network. I did not realize that my primary account did not have automatic administration privileges so I granted them. I retained the same hotmail account and password. After the current update I noticed that my primary computer was behaving erratically, not as a result of the account change I believe but probably a synchronization issue with a NAS server and another network issue.  So I decided to restore the computer to a recover point of about 2 weeks ago.
When I rebooted - the left click on the command prompt - it now does not work.  So my new consolidated mail - or any of the Microsoft utilities are now invisible.

I then created another local account (non microsoft) and everything for that account is normal. So I am now sure that the account creation utility has bugs.
I have run all the  recommended utilities too cleanup the image - but my accounts are still messed up.  Apart from that - there are no  other issues that I have discovered.

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to transfer the administration rights to another account - but cannot then fix my primary user account to which all the microsoft utilities and mail etc are linked.

Any ideas about how to fix this mess ?

Comment: "So I am now sure that the account creation utility has bugs." - Doubtful the utility has not changed in 15 years.

Answer (score 0):

Update.  I restored again - to an earlier recovery point - but first I changed the account permissions back to what I believe they were at that time.  This time I recovered my profile, my start menu, my programs and as close as possible to normal.  It is in the midst of an automatic windows 10 update, so I still have no access to the windows application shop.  Here is my takeaway:  do NOT create Microsoft type logins (i.e. using a hotmail account) unless a far more comprehensive document can be located regarding the many issues that can be triggered.  The account process is very very poorly explained - it is fraught with synchronization problems which can bite you easily - and there is simply no clear way to fix the mess. For example - if you have more than one computer on the same network (as do I - another as a redundant backup) - there is nothing to stop you from using the same hotmail account - name - and password on each computer - without making them roving logins.   Secondly - be very judicious about what you make available as 'off line' data.  That can also tie everything up in knots - Microsoft pushes these things because they want to sell you cloud space eventually (all of this synchronization takes cloud space that you do not own.